# Printing a two dimensional array to a message box - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write the second two 'columns' of a dynamic array to a message box in a readable form. Is this possible?

I then want for if the user clicks 'OK' for the sub to continue, and if the user clicks cancel then I would like the sub to stop.

The code loading the array is as follows:

```
ReDim table(tableSize, 1 To 3)   ' set array length

i = 1
c = 1
Do While Worksheets("Items").Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

    If Worksheets("Items").Cells(i, 2).Value = item Then    'load array
        table(c, 1) = i
        table(c, 2) = Worksheets("Items").Cells(i, 4)
        table(c, 3) = Worksheets("Items").Cells(i, 10)
        c = c + 1
    End If

    i = i + 1
Loop
```

I was trying to use a `foreach`   loop but I don't know if that is the best way or not, and I couldn't work it out. To make it slightly more complicated I want to include a string before and after the printed out array.

Comment: @findwindow I cannot work out how to populate the message box at all so there is nothing in it.

Comment: Well, you need to show what you've tried. You can't expect SO to just write the code for you.

Comment: If that's how you load it, why not just build the string up as you load the array?

Comment: Inside the loop, before incrementing c, `myStr = myStr & " " & table(c, 2)`. After the loop `MsgBox myStr`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get a "table-style" message:

```
Sub MessyMessage()
    msg = ""

    For Each r In Range("A:A")
        If r.Value = "" Then Exit For
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & r.Value & vbTab & r.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next r

    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

[image]